# How add email id in Email API Authorized Senders list on gae java

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, google-api

I want to add Gmail Email id in Email API Authorized Senders list on gae java. but when i added email id in Email API Authorized Senders list then GAE say :

> Unable to Add Authorized Senders,  You don't have permission to add
>   these users to the authorized senders list.

Why google throwing this message ? How can i add senders email id in Email API Authorized list?

Answer (score 3):

All email addresses on the Email API Authorized Senders list need to be valid Gmail or Google-hosted domain accounts. App Administrators can add the following accounts to the list of Authorized Senders:

- Their own email address.
- Any group for which they are an Owner or Manager.
- For applications hosted in a Google Apps domain: noreply@domain.com, as long as noreply@domain.com is a valid account (user or group).

Comment: Thank you Vadim for your valuable responsible. i want to know who is administrator for my app? how shall i add administrator to my app?

Comment: @vijaychougule - the administrator of the app is one of the project's owners under which your app is hosted.

Comment: thank you for your response but could you please explain in detail i am new in gae. i am not getting. what is the project owners how shall i know it?